# C# linq split ,order by and join the value

Tags: c#, linq

I Have below code . it working as I am excepting. but I want to reduce the number of line code. In the foreach loop i am doing split ,order by and join the value. so other way we can write it ?

```
class a
{
 public string Test { get; set; }
 public string Code { get; set; }
}

var masterFormList = "BBB,AAA,CCC,FFF,GGG,HHH";
List<a> mData = new List<a>();
 
mData.Add(new a { Test = "AAA,BBB,CCC,FFF,GGG,HHH", Code = "A" });
mData.Add(new a { Test = "BBB", Code = "B" });
mData.Add(new a { Test = "CCC", Code = "C" });
mData.Add(new a { Test = "FFF", Code = "D" });
mData.Add(new a { Test = "GGG", Code = "E" });
mData.Add(new a { Test = "HHH", Code = "F" });
var masterSet = masterFormList.Split(',').OrderBy(y => y);
var l = string.Join(",", masterSet);
    
    
string value = "";
foreach (var item in mData)
{
   var listSplite = item.Test.Split(',').OrderBy(y => y);
     if (l == string.Join(",", listSplite))
     {
     value = item.Code;
    
      }
  }
```

Comment: The code is incomplete, the loop is insignificant, please finish it first.

Comment: I have added more code. logic is i  have one value it contain multiple value with comma. so i want to check the value with each list item. list object value also have comma

Comment: Now it's almost one line in the foreach loop. Do you still feel dissatisfied? A further reduction I can image is using List.Find instead of foreach: `mData.Find(item => string.Join(",", item.Test.Split(',').OrderBy(y => y)) == l)?.Code`

Comment: Your sample data really doesn't exercise your code at all...

Answer (score 0):

As I see you want to find elements that have given list of codes in `Test` property. For that I'd write help method and use LINQ methods as below:

```
var masterFormList = "BBB,AAA,CCC,FFF,GGG,HHH";

List<ExampleClass> mData = new List<ExampleClass>();

mData.Add(new ExampleClass { Test = "AAA,BBB,CCC,FFF,GGG,HHH", Code = "A" });
mData.Add(new ExampleClass { Test = "BBB", Code = "B" });
mData.Add(new ExampleClass { Test = "CCC", Code = "C" });
mData.Add(new ExampleClass { Test = "FFF", Code = "D" });
mData.Add(new ExampleClass { Test = "GGG", Code = "E" });
mData.Add(new ExampleClass { Test = "HHH", Code = "F" });

// You can use here also Where method that will return list of items
var masterItem = mData.FirstOrDefault(x => AreListsEquivalent(masterFormList, x.Test));

Console.ReadKey();

// Helper method to compare list in form of comma separated values.
static bool AreListsEquivalent(string list1, string list2)
{

    return list1.Split(',').ToHashSet()
        .SetEquals(list2.Split(',').ToHashSet());
}

// Test class
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the original code as shown appears to return LastOrDefault instead of first.

Comment: Also, while not an unreasonable assumption, this answer assumes that duplicate values aren't important.

Comment: I would also suggest that the overhead of creating `HashSets` (calling `GetHashCode` per string) and then `SetEquals` (calling `GetHashCode` per string on one side again and then comparing the strings) is much more than just comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do your string comparisons, but be a bit more abbreviated by using LINQ:

```
var masterKey = String.Join(",", masterFormList.Split(',').OrderBy(y => y));

var value = mData.Where(a => masterKey == String.Join(",", a.Test.Split(',').OrderBy(y => y)))
                 .LastOrDefault()
                 ?.Code;
```